# Standalone websocket client

Tags: node.js, websocket, wordpress-rest-api

I need to websocket client that receive data from another websocket server (websocket API), and then send this data to my wordpress site (custom endpoint - rest API).

Can you recommend good solution for this? I have read about nodejs websocket module, but is there any other good standalone webksocket clients?

Thank you.

Comment: Little details. I want to receive data from the server (API) using WebSockets and then handle this data and re-send some part of it my rest api (wordpress rest api).

Comment: On client or server side ? the [`ws`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws) module is pretty good (node.js)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this isn't the best answer but you can try Socket.io (https://socket.io/).

It enables bidirectional data transfer from browser(client) to server, is well documented and a widely used in open source projects.

Comment: Thanks but: 

Socket.IO is NOT a WebSocket implementation. Although Socket.IO indeed uses WebSocket as a transport when possible, it adds additional metadata to each packet. That is why a WebSocket client will not be able to successfully connect to a Socket.IO server, **and a Socket.IO client will not be able to connect to a plain WebSocket server either.**

Comment: socket.io is not a plain websocket client. It use websockets as transport.